# The Bessel Function Bessel$J_0(\sqrt{2x})$ is uniformly convergent on $[x_0-1, x_0+1]$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Please note that this is a "follow up" of my previous question [$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(n!)^2}\left( \frac{x}{2}\right)^n $ is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561407/fx-sum-n-0-infty-frac-1nn2-left-fracx2-rightn-i). I decided to accept the answer given there because under the circumstances I was asking the question the answers I got were sufficient. I now have the possibility to refine the question and show where I need some help.

> Show that $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(n!)^2}\left( \frac{x}{2} \right)^n$$ converges uniformly on the interval $ [x_0-1, x_0+1]$

**Introduction**: First allow me to highlight that **we did not cover** the *Weierstrass-M-Test* (Criteria) for uniform convergence, from what I have read from various online resources (including exercise videos) the Weierstrass-M-Test seems to be one of the strongest tools to check for uniform convergence.

**Question**: Is it possible to show that the Bessel Function converges uniformly on $[x_0-1,x_0+1]$ by using the same technique as in the example given.

**Example**: Allow me to demonstrate the way we did this in class with examples I do understand (the examples are simple, the tough ones are left for us but 'should' be possible to be handled in the same way).

$f_n(x) = \frac{x}{n}$ where $x \in [0,1]$ such that $f_{n}(x)=0$ for $n \to \infty$ (point wise convergence)

$|f_n(x)-0|= \left| \frac{x}{n} \right|= \frac{x}{n}\leq \frac{1}{n} \to 0$ for $ n \to \infty$ (uniform convergence on the intervall)

**Counterexample**:

$$f_n(x)= \frac{n^2x}{1+(nx)^4},  \ x \in [ 0,1] \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)=0 \tag{point wise }$$
Let $x_n= \frac{1}{n}$
$$ \implies f_n(x_n)=\frac{n}{2}\implies |f_n(x_n)-0|= \frac{n}{2}> \epsilon  \\ \implies  \text{ not uniform convergence}$$

**Back to the Bessel Function**: It is easy to show that the Bessel Function converges using the d'Alembert Criteria (Ratio Test). However, I cannot say to which value the Bessel Function converges, which is crucial for the method introduced above. Furthermore, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f_n(x)$ the Bessel Function is a polynomial and therefore continuous, especially continuous on a given $x_0$. And here I am stuck.

**With Weierstrass-M**: Supplementary for this question but I will still add my approach:

fix $x_0=2$ such that the Intervall becomes $[1,3]$ then $$\frac{1}{(n!)^2}\left( \frac{x}{2}\right)^n \leq \frac{1}{(n!)^2}\left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^n=:M_n$$
which seems to go wrong for n approaching infinity the given $M$ would tend to zero and fall out of the given interval.

Comment: It might help if you tell what $x_0$ is.  Just any point?  Then you are to show uniform convergence on any interval of length 2.  Do you know some connection between uniform convergence and radius of convergence of a power series?

Comment: $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ a point on which the Bessel function is continuous. For my approach with the Weierstrass-M-Criteria I fixed that value to $x_0=2$ because it seemed to me to be a valid step, considering that the polynomials (described through the Bessel function) are continuous everywhere.

Comment: " Do you know some connection between uniform convergence and radius of convergence of a power series?" in an earlier exercise I had to show that the Bessel function was well-defined, I did this by checking if the Bessel function converges and it did $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, so for this particular exercise I did not need a radius of convergence, however it is my first example that introduces the Radius of convergence and I am not entirely familiar with it. It seems clear to me that the function must be continuous within that radius though.